# View count not incrementing for meta page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta

[This page](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216/system-for-regional-questions) has a view count of zero.

[image: This picture is broken]

This has to be wrong because the question has been upvoted and answered.

Here is the full page:
[image]

Comment: Has a view count of 2 now...

Comment: I'd suggest asking about this on Meta SO, with a [bug] tag.

Answer (score 1):

As Neil pointed out, we buffer these view counts and write them out periodically, so nothing to be worried about -- unless it's stuck at 0 for a whole day or so.

Comment: it took about a full day to increment from zero to three.  If you look at the screenshots you can see that freiheit left an answer 21 hours ago and the view count was still not incremented.  Maybe this is the intended behavior but it seems a bit on the long side.

Answer (score 0):

The page now has a view count of three. Perhaps it was just slow in catching up?